# How to set cookie in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, cookies, vue.js, vuejs2

What is the best practice for setting a cookie in vuejs?
I use SSR, so I guess I can’t use localStorage.

What is the best approach here?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could use the [vue-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookie) or [vue-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies) npm package.
You can set a cookie in the created method.

```
created() {
   this.$cookie.set("keyName", keyValue, "expiring time")
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to `this.$cookies.set("keyName", keyValue, "expiring time")`. You either forgot the s or it has been updated but it doesn't work anymore if you just write `$cookie`

Comment: @AndorNémeth For vue-cookie, it's `this.$cookie`, for vue-cookies it's `this.$cookies`

Comment: @Semx11 daaamn I missed that. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: [vue-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookie)  only supports vue-2 hence [vue-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies) for vue-3

Answer (score 40):

You can also do it in a plain JavaScript without using extensions.

Lets say you want to store a token with expiry of 24 hours inside `axios` POST response.

```js
axios
  .post("url", dataToSend)
  .then(function (response) {
    if (response.status == 200) {
      let d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      let expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
      document.cookie =
        "Token=" + response.data.Token + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [vue-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies)

To use:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-cookies@1.5.12/vue-cookies.js"></script>
<script>
  $cookies.set('cookie_name', 'cookie_value');
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest and cleanest way is:

```
    import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies'
    VueCookies.set('name' , name, "1h")
```

This could be added in mutations if you want them in Vuex.

Answer (score -10):

it would be best to use `mounted` method

```
mounted: function() { 
    document.cookie = "username=John Doe";
}
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer.

Comment: mounted :function(){ document.cookie = "username=John Doe";  } . If Dom is ready mounted will be trigger so that you can mention your cookie data

Comment: Please edit your answer to make it more complete and understandable.

Comment: Wouldn't it trigger every single time you refreshed the app? Terrific.

Comment: Please try to include more details